# Prevent a function from becoming an instancemethod in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, portability, python-2.x

I'm writing some code that works in Python 3 but not Python 2.

```
foo = lambda x: x + "stuff"

class MyClass(ParentClass):
    bar = foo

    def mymethod(self):
        return self.bar(self._private_stuff)
```

I would want it to simply print the private stuff, but if I try to run mymethod, I get:

```
TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Of course, the above is not the actual code, but a simplification of the real thing. I wanted to do it like this because I need to pass along private information that I don't want to expose the final user to i.e. anybody that extends my classes. But in Python 2, the global level lambda (or any plain function) become an `instancemethod`, which is unwanted in this case!

What do you recommend me to make this piece of code portable?

Comment: It has to be said: if someone can extend your classes, you can't keep information private from them.

Comment: I don't want the other people to need to know how to do the self._private stuff. They can if they want to. But that's why I'm writing this, so they don't need to.

Comment: I don't see how it could work in Py3. The situation here is nearly the same, except that I get a different message: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` - while Py2 gives me the nearly identical message `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.

Answer (score 8):

Simplest:

```
class MyClass(ParentClass):
    bar = staticmethod(foo)
```

with the rest of your code staying the same.  While `staticmethod` is most often used as a "decorator", there is no requirement to do so (thus, no requirement for a further level of indirection to have `bar` be a decorated method calling `foo`).

Answer (score 4):

I would go with Alex Martelli's suggestion. Just for the record, though, (I wrote this answer before seeing Alex Martelli's beautiful answer) you can also do the following in Python 2.7 and 3.x (note especially the documentation links I have provided, so that you understand what is going on):

You can use a [static method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod), which will not expect an implicit first argument. Note that [lambda expressions cannot take statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda), so you will not be able to use the `print` statement in your `lambda` function in 2.x.

```
foo = lambda x: x            # note that you cannot use print here in 2.x

class MyClass(object):

    @staticmethod            # use a static method
    def bar(x):
        return foo(x)        # or simply print(foo(x))

    def mymethod(self):
        return self.bar(1)

>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.mymethod()
1
```

Comment: Right right! My bad, but this is anyway useful. Updated my question to reflect that.